# Email a user when they are assigned as case manager?

Tags: email, civicase, civirules

Can anyone advise on the best way of sending an email to a newly assigned case manager/advisor? (ie to a specific case relationship when it is first made)

I've looked at the civirules extension but could only get it to send to both parties (client as well) and without any case specific tokens to tell them what it was regarding..

thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For sending a message to new case managers - I would suggest using Scheduled Reminders.

- Create a new group "Case Managers". Add all case managers to the group.
- Set a Scheduled Reminder on "Activity" of type "Open Case".
- Limit recipients to members of the group "Case Managers".

With regard to the tokens - there has been recent work to support case tokens on activities.  See [CRM-19767](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19767) and the accompanying [casetokens](https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.casetokens) extension.  Note that I'm not sure that this will extend the functionality to Scheduled Reminders - but if it doesn't, I imagine it will get a coder 80% of the way there.

Answer (score 2):

You could also fund the development of your solution in the CiviRules extension.